# How do I change the background color on a shiny dashboard in R

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I love the new shiny dashboard package in R. I am trying to customize the appearance and its proving difficult. I want to change the background color of the app to white.

Here is what I have done.

I have added a custom.css file to a www directory. 
It has this code.

```
body > .content-wrapper .right-side {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have successfully changed the title font with the example [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css) so I know that my css file is working.

I have also used inspect element to find the color in the css and changed it successfully from the developer console.

However the background color will not change when I set the color in my css file.

Answer (score 16):

Adding this to the custom.css file worked...

I found this in the css file for the adminLTE in the shiny dashboard repo.

```
.content-wrapper,
.right-side {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change the background, in the ui.R after

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
```

you can add this code:

```
tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('
        body, label, input, button, select { 
            font-family: "Calibri";
            background-color: black;
        }')
    )),
```